# cant find how my observable is triggered automatically

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Apologies if its a dump question.

I have the code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {


    let data$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      observer.next('message 1');
    });
      
    data$.subscribe(s => console.log(s));
  }
```

I can see the message 1 is there in console output. I am not able to understand that how and when observer.next is called?

I have take `data$` variable which has an Observable object. But why the observer.Next is calling automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observer function is called when you `subscribe` to your observable. You can see this behaviour when you use subscribe multiple times with a random value like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

const source$ = new Observable(observer => observer.next(Math.random()));

source$.subscribe(console.log); // Random number
source$.subscribe(console.log); // A different random number
```

This behaviour is called *cold observable* and [this a good article explaining this](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) (and the difference between *hot* and *cold* observables. Additionally, here a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-psktss?file=index.ts) for the above example.

Comment: this is confusing to me because a subscriber is deciding the when the data is published from observer

Comment: Think of it as a stream that starts producing values as soon as someone wants to listen to these values. That is contrary to hot observables, that produce values - if someone is listening or not. Both are concepts that you might need or might not need. Your code, though, does produce a cold observable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Observable`like this

`let data$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => { observer.next('message 1') });`

**Is a loaded gun**, but **to pull the trigger is by calling this** `.subscribe(...)`